# VLC sound changes when in other program

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

I've got a very strange problem in VLC. When I am watching a video, the sound changes if I open another program while VLC is running. Then, when I open up VLC again (say I Alt-Tab to VLC), the sound changes back. To be clear, all this time VLC is running, it is just a matter which program is sort of opened (don't know the proper way of saying this). So if VLC were running while typing this, the sound would change once I click on the VLC icon to watch the video.

It seems there is more surround sound when I am not in VLC, which is actually what I'd prefer.

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can solve it?

Comment: Can you look at the "master volume" or have a mixer that shows volume levels of programs/inputs and "master"? Sounds like some programs are changing the master volume on their own, but monitoring the volume levels should show what's going on

Comment: I believe that the phrase you’re looking for is ‘‘which window has focus’’.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was Dolby audio.

When VLC is in the **foreground**, Dolby audio is in the **movie mode**.

When it is in the **background**, Dolby audio is in the **music mode**.

I make it **movie mode** and problem solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also have a similar problem, and I think it has appeared after the latest Windows 10 update to version 1803.

However my problem was with the Dolby Atmos being turned ON, which I turned OFF.

[image: Audio Settings - Dolby]

Post this, the audio change, as Scott points out, does not happen on focus change.

Comment: this was the same with me though the setting was titled "Dolby Audio"

Comment: Edit: this is not a problem anymore in 1809.